# How to restart GNU make (without causing an error)

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I need to restart the `make` process in case some intermediate target gets (re)build.

This is the case when a PIP requirements file gets (re)compiled, because the checksum of the resulting file is used in the path to the virtualenv that is used in the Makefile.
If the requirements file gets updated, the same `$(MAKECMDGOALS)` should get rebuild from the beginning.

I have come up with the following, but this requires to make the outer/inital make process fail (`exit 1`), which I would like to avoid.

```
foo:
    echo "foo"

    # Need to restart make if this has been used as intermediate target.
    if [ $(MAKECMDGOALS) != "$@" ]; then \
        echo "Restarting make..."; \
        touch $@; \
        $(MAKE) $(MAKECMDGOALS); \
        exit 1; \
    fi

bar: foo
    echo "bar"

.PHONY: bar
```

Comment: Only if it has been rebuilt as an *intermediate* target?

Comment: Yes, there's no point in restarting if the affected target has been called explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A makefile on the lines below might fit the bill. `bar` and `baz` are goals 
that will be sabotaged if they intermediately make `foo` (a.k.a *tricky* goals).
There's no *restarting* involved: instead, it is arranged that the tricky
goals are *only* made by a fresh `$(MAKE)`, after the top make has ensured `foo` is
up-to-date.

```
.phony: all clean

tricky = bar baz

all:
    $(MAKE) $(tricky)

foo:
    echo "foo"
    touch $@

clean:
    rm -f foo

ifndef simple
tricky_goals = $(filter $(tricky),$(MAKECMDGOALS))
ifneq ($(tricky_goals),)
$(tricky_goals): foo
    $(MAKE) simple=y $@
endif

else # ifndef simple
# All tricky goals follow...

bar: foo
    echo "bar"

baz: foo
    echo "baz"

endif # ifndef simple
```

The behaviour depends on whether the variable `simple` is defined, which
by default it is not.

If `simple` is defined then the goals, whatever they are, will be made
the obvious way - the way they'd be made if it weren't for the `foo` pitfall.

If `simple` is undefined then `tricky_goals` becomes the tricky members `$(MAKECMDGOALS)`. 
If `$(tricky_goals)` is empty there is nothing tricky to do. Otherwise the target list 
`$(tricky_goals)` becomes dependent on `foo`. So if `foo` is out-of-date, it gets made now.
Finally each tricky goal is made by calling a simple `$(MAKE)` for it,
in which `foo` will be up-todate. Any non-tricky goals will be made the simple way.

I've included `all` and `clean` goals for completeness. Note that `all`
needs coded to go the tricky way.

Comment: Thanks! I have not tested it, because I have solved it in a different way already (but similar): I use `$(if ...)` to either start the sub-make with the same `$(MAKECMDGOALS)` (and other command line arguments) or generate the rule.